# Table row data not extending far enough for on hover change background color

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I'm extremely new with CSS**

My hover over is producing a poor result. See the image below:

[image]

**If you look the yellow ends substantially before the grey border above finishes.**

```
                <div class="section2">
                <div class="bannersection">
                <h2 class="sectionlabel"><xsl:value-of select="/*/hundreds/highestreviews/label" /></h2><a href="/top/highestreviews"><span class="reviewlink" style="margin-right:390px">View Clubs</span></a>
                </div>
                <table class="featuredclub" id="featuredclub-highestreviews">
                                            <tr>
                            <td width="10%" class="rating"><div class="ratingnumber"><span class="ratingpositiontext">#1</span></div></td>
                            <td width="15%" style="margin-left:0px;margin-top:1px" class="imagetd"><div class="ratingimage"><div style="margin-top:6px"><img style="height:80px;width:80px" class="featuredavatar" src="/img/featuredtmp.png" /></div></div></td>
                            <td width="75%" style="text-align:left;margin-left:10px">
                                <span class="featuredclubname"><xsl:value-of select="/*/hundreds/highestreviews/featuredclub/name"/></span>
                                <span class="featuredclubaddress"><xsl:value-of select="/*/hundreds/highestreviews/featuredclub/address"/></span>
                                <span class="featuredclublocality"><xsl:value-of select="/*/hundreds/highestreviews/featuredclub/city"/>, <xsl:value-of select="/*/hundreds/highestreviews/featuredclub/state"/> <xsl:value-of select="/*/hundreds/highestreviews/featuredclub/zip"/></span>
                                <div class="featuredclubphone"><xsl:value-of select="/*/hundreds/highestreviews/featuredclub/phone"/></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                <p class="clear"></p>
                        <table width="95%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-left:-50px">
                            <xsl:for-each select="/*/hundreds/highestreviews/contendors/contendor">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right" width="60%"><span style="margin-right:25px" class="clubname" id="highestreviews-{./locid}-{position()}"><xsl:value-of select="./name"/></span></td>
                                    <td align="right" width="35%">
                                    <div class="progress-fill" style="margin-left:5px;width:{./pixelweight}px"></div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="right" width="5%"><span class="value" style="margin-left:15px;"><span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="./numberval"/></span></span></td>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:for-each>                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                        </table>            
            </div>
            <p class="clear"></p>
        </div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
    @CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

    span.value {
        margin-right:-10px;
    }
    .viewallbutton{
        display:inline;
        margin-top:2px;
        margin-left:2px;
    }
    h2.sectionlabel{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .banner{
      position: relative;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      width: 1200px;
      height: 66px;
      margin: 0px auto;
      padding-top:15px;
      padding-bottom:0px;
      padding-left:16px;
      padding-right:25px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      /**
      border-top: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
      border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
      border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
      border-bottom:none;
      */
      border:0px;
      border-bottom:1px solid #f0f0f0;
      font: 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    }
    .banner h2{
      font: 32px/32px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
      color: #120006;
      margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding-top:5px;
      padding-bottom:15px;
    }
    div.banner-container1{
        width:90%;
        height:50px;
        background-color:#f0f0f0;
        padding-left:25px;
    }
    div.banner-container2{
        width:90%;
        height:50px;
        background-color:#f0f0f0;
        padding-left:25px;
        /**padding-left:25px;*/
    }
    div.banner-container div.innerclubbox{
        background-color:#ffffff;   
    }
    .tabledatalabel{
      font: 20px/24px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
      color: #606060;
      margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
      /**text-transform:capitalize;*/
      padding-top:5px;  
    }
    .row {
      position: relative;
      /**height: 750px;*/
      height: 450px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      width: 1200px;
      margin: 0px auto;
      /**padding-top:20px;*/
      padding-top:10px;
      padding-bottom:0px;
      padding-left:0px;
      /**padding-right:25px;*/
      box-sizing: border-box;
      /**border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;*/
      font: 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;     
    }
    p .clear{
      clear:both;
    }

    .section1 .featuredclub{
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        background-color:#f0f0f0;
        font:14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Sserif;  
    }

    .section1 table.featuredclub,
    .section2 table.featuredclub{
        width:100%;
        height:111px;
        background-color:#f0f0f0;
        font:14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Sserif;
        margin-top:-5px;
        /**margin-left:25px;*/
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }

    .section1 table.featuredclub .rating,
    .section2 table.featuredclub .rating {
        /**margin-top:-5px;
        margin-left:25px;
        margin-bottom:10px;*/
        /**background-color:#ffffff;*/
        width:71px;
        height:71px;
    }

    .section1 table.featuredclub .image,
    .section2 table.featuredclub .image {
        /**margin-top:-5px;
        margin-left:25px;
        margin-bottom:10px;*/
        /**background-color:#ffffff;*/
        width:71px;
        height:71px;
        margin-left:0px;
    }
    .ratingnumber{
        font-size: 42px;
        margin-left:16px;
        width:80px;
        height:80px;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        /**padding-left:15px;
        padding-top:15px;*/
    }
    .section1 .featuredclub span,
    .section2 .featuredclub span {
       line-height: 85px;
    }
    .ratingpositiontext{
        margin-right:15px;
        margin-top:55px;
    }
    .section1 table.featuredclub .rating div.ratingimage,
    .section2 table.featuredclub .rating div.ratingimage{
        font-size: 26px;
        margin-left:0px;
        width:80px;
        height:80px;
        background-color:#ffffff;
    }
    .section1 .featuredclub .featuredtext{
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        background-color:#f0f0f0;
        font:14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Sserif;
        display:inline-block;   
    }

    .section1 .featuredclub span p.rating{  
        margin-top:-5px;
        margin-left:25px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        width:71px;
        height:71px;
        /**display:inline;*/
    }

    .section1 .featuredclub span p.text{    
        margin-top:-5px;
        margin-left:5px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        /**width:71px;*/
        height:71px;
        display:inline;
    }

    .section2 .featuredclub{
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        background-color:#f0f0f0;
        font:14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Sserif;
    }

    .section1 .featuredclub span.featuredclubname,
    .section2 .featuredclub span.featuredclubname
    {
        clear:both;
        color:#120006;
        float:left;
        font: 22px/22px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
    }
    .section1 .featuredclub span.featuredclubaddress,
    .section2 .featuredclub span.featuredclubaddress
    {
        clear:both;
        float:left;
        font: 14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Serif;
        color: #000000;
    }
    .section1 .featuredclub span.featuredclublocality,
    .section2 .featuredclub span.featuredclublocality
    {
        clear:both;
        float:left;
        font: 14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Serif;
        color: #000000;
    }
    .section1 .featuredclub div.featuredclubphone,
    .section2 .featuredclub div.featuredclubphone
    {
        position: relative;
        clear:both;
        float:left;
        font: bold 12px/12px Arial, Helvtica, Sans-serif;
        margin-top:2px; 
        height: 18px;
        font: bold 14px/14px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
        padding: 1px 0px 0px 22px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEgASALMAADMzAJmZZv///8/Pz87OzszMzJmZmWlpaWZmZjMzMwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACwAAAAAEgASAAAEWFDISatNiCaVjBWIonhSsHEEZYgKYK3KMLEiiUkFN9OFUJyelY3V0ygkOh+xkstsJqeERWeQ7hTFSbYCw34+oeS3chpJNodxmSbaUsJssSXHto4F1dp9HwEAOw==) 0px 0px no-repeat;
    }

    .section2 .featuredclub span p.rating,
    {
        margin-top:-5px;
        margin-left:25px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        width:71px;
        height:71px;
    }

    .section1 .featuredclub p.rating img.featuredavatar{
        margin-top:-27px;
        width:70px;
        height:70px;
        margin-left:69px;
        display:block;
    }

    .section2 .featuredclub p.rating img.featuredavatar{
        margin-top:-27px;
        width:70px;
        height:70px;
        margin-left:69px;
    }

    .section1 .featuredclub span p.rating span.rating-number-box
    {
        text-align:center;
        font-size: 36px;
        color:#bd673a;
        margin-top:20px;
    }

    .section2 .featuredclub span p.rating span.rating-number-box
    {
        text-align:center;
        font-size: 36px;
        color:#bd673a;
        margin-top:20px;
    }

    .section1 .featuredclub span{
        /**margin-left:25px;*/  
    }

    .section2 .featuredclub span{
        /**margin-left:25px;*/  
    }

    .section1 {
      width:50%;
      border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
      float:left;  
      box-sizing: border-box;   
    }

    td {
        font:14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Sserif;
    }

    .section2 {
      width:50%;
      /**border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;*/
      float:left;  
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .section1 h2{
      font: 22px/24px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
      color: #120006;
      margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding-left:17px;
      padding-bottom:10px;
    }

    .section2 h2{
      font: 22px/24px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
      color: #120006;
      margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding-left:17px;
      padding-bottom:10px;
    }

    td {
        text-align:right;
    }
    td.imagetd{
        text-align:left;
    }

    .progress-bar .horizontal {
      float: left;
      height: 45px;
      width: 100%;
      /**padding: 12px 0;*/
    }

    .progress-track {
      position: relative;
      width: 30%;
      height: 13px;
      background: #FFFFFF;
      float:right;
      margin-left:-20px;
    }

    .progress-fill {
      position: relative;
      background: #2272af;
      height: 13px;
      width: 50%;
      color: #2272af;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: "Lato","Verdana",sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 20px;
      border-radius:0px 4px 4px 0px;
      /**border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px;*/
      /**border-radius-top-right:5x;
      border-radius-bottom-right:5px;*/
    }

    /**tr td { padding-top: 1px }*/
    .ratingpositiontext{
        color:#e8620d;
        font: 42px/44px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
    }

    .featuredclub { border-collapse: collapse; }
    td { padding: 0; }

    span.reviewlink {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;  
      font: 16px/16px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
      color: #000000;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      background:url(data:image/png;base64,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) right 0px no-repeat;
      padding: 3px 11px 2px 4px;  
      #if gecko
            line-height: 0.95;
            /**bottom: -1px;*/  
      #endif  
    }
```

And finally here is my javascript:

```
        var hundreds = document.getElementsByClassName("clubname");
        for(var i=0;i<hundreds.length;i++){
            hundreds[i].onmouseover = function(e){          
                var firstParent = this.parentNode;
                firstParent.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="#ffff99";
                firstParent.parentNode.style.cursor='pointer';
                updateFeaturedData(this);
            }
            hundreds[i].onmouseout = function(e){           
                var firstParent = this.parentNode;
                firstParent.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="#ffffff";
                firstParent.parentNode.style.cursor='default';
            }
        }
```

Anyway any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a fiddle of that code...

Comment: Not a solution, but the highlight should really just be done with CSS. Recreating a basic `:hover` state with javascript is overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is caused by the negative margin right given to the span.value

The negative margin move the element outside the table space.